# Finding the expectation of a random variable given a CDF with a floor operator

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I have to compute the expectation of the random variable $X$ with CDF
$$
F_X(x)=\dfrac{1}{27}\min\{\lfloor x\rfloor, 3\}^3, \quad\text{for } x\geq 0
$$
I then first consider the case when $0\leq x \leq 3$. Then I get the derivative
$$
F_X'(x)=f_X(x)=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{1}{27}\lfloor x \rfloor^3\right)
$$
But how would I compute this? I read that the derivative of the floor function when $x$ is an integer is undefined, whereas when  $x$ is not an integer, the derivative is equal to zero. Should I compute the expectation in a different way?

Comment: Why looking for a density? Not all random variables have densities. In your case, $X$ is discrete with jumps at $1,2,3$. Can you try to finish now? Or you can proceed directly, there is a formula for an expectation of non-negative random variable in terms of CDF, namely $\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^{\infty}(1-F_X(t))dt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using distribution functions:** Observe that you can write your distribution function as $F(x) = G(x)^3$ where $G(x) = \frac{1}{3}\min\{\lfloor x\rfloor,3\}$. Here, $G$ is another distribution function of a discrete random variable taking values in $\{1,2,3\}$ with equal probability. Taking power $3$ changes the probabilities, but not the fact that it still remains a discrete random variable taking values in $\{1,2,3\}$. Hence $X$ is a discrete random variable with probabilities
$$P(X=1)=\frac{1}{27}, \quad P(X=2)=\frac{7}{27}, \quad P(X=3)=\frac{19}{27}.$$
Therefore, the expected value is given by
$$E[X]= 1\frac{1}{27} + 2\frac{7}{27}+3\frac{19}{27}=\frac{8}{3}.$$

This is also the result you would get by averaging out using the definition of expectation as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, i.e.
$$E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xdF(x),$$
where the integral above is to be understood as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral. In practice it is computed as
$$E[X]= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\dot{f}(x)dx + \sum_i x_i(F(x_i)-F(x_i-)),$$
where $\dot{f}$ denotes the derivative of $F$ at points where $F$ is differentiable and $x_i$ are the discontinuity points of $F$. Here, $F(x_i-)=\lim_{\substack{y\to x_i \\ y<x_i}}F(y)$ denotes the left limit.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great explanation! Just to be clear. The reason that the random variable takes on values $\{1, 2, 3\}$ is due to the fact that F(x) takes on distinct values for exactly $x=1, x=2,$ and $x=3$?

Comment: The reason why $X$ can take values $1$, $2$ and $3$ with positive probability, that is $P(X=1)$, $P(X=2)$ and $P(X=3)$ are positive, is because $F$ has discontinuities (jumps) at those points. These are usually called "atoms". In this case, these are actually the only values $X$ takes, because otherwise outside $x=1,2,3$ the function $F$ is constant, and hence $f=0$. But you can have random variables with $P(X\in [a,b])>0$ and $P(X=c)=0$ for $c\in [a,b]$ and still some atoms say, in $\mathbb{R}-[a,b]$. These are continuous random variables, but not absolutely continuous :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that prove

$\mathbb{E(X)} = \displaystyle \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x))dx \,$ (for a non-negative random variable), where $F_X(x)$ is CDF.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Formulas_for_special_cases

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10159/find-expected-value-using-cdf

Given we have a discrete random variable, we do not have density. So we would rather apply the above formula to calculate Expectation.

$\mathbb{E(X)} = \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} (1- min[\frac{(\lfloor x \rfloor)^3}{27},3])dx \,$

$= \displaystyle \int_0^1 (1- 0)dx + \int_1^2 (1- \frac{1}{27})dx + \int_2^3 (1- \frac{8}{27})dx + \int_3^{\infty} (1- \frac{27}{27})dx$

$= \displaystyle 1 + \frac{26}{27} + \frac{19}{27} = \frac{8}{3}$